# Unicode rendering (Updated)

Tags: c++, unicode

I posted my question couple days ago while i was still working on my code. I will restate my question so it would be clear for everyone.

Goal: print All of the Unicodes available using a loop.

[image]

Question: why I can only print them, as symbols, if they were hardcoded in a string rather then a variable.

Output:

```
U000000

U000001

U000002

...

U000017

U000018
```

---

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    const int HexBase=16;
    const int HexMax=15;
    const int UniCharMaxPrint=1000;
    const int ASCCIAlphaCapBase=48;

    int main() {

        int DecNum = 0;
        int sizeHex= 3;

        for (int j=0; j < UniCharMaxPrint; j++)//prints 100 unviersal Chars
        {
            int DecNumCopy = DecNum;
            int resultDiv =0;
            string HexChar=" ";
            string HexNum ="X";
            string UniNum ="u";
            string BackSlash = "\\";
            string full="HI ";
            for (int i = sizeHex; i >=0; i--)
            {

                //Dec calcultion
                resultDiv = (DecNumCopy/(int)(pow(HexBase,i)));
                DecNumCopy = DecNumCopy - ((int)(pow(HexBase,i)) * resultDiv);
                if ((i==0) && (resultDiv>HexMax)){cout <<"Error # is Too large"<<endl;}//Check if the number entered is big or not

                //Get the equivalente Hex charcter
                if ((resultDiv >= 0)&&(resultDiv <= 9))
                { HexChar = ASCCIAlphaCapBase + resultDiv;}
                else if ((resultDiv >= 10)&&(resultDiv <= 15))
                {   switch (resultDiv)
                    {   case 10 : {HexChar='a'; break;};
                        case 11 : {HexChar='b'; break;};
                        case 12 : {HexChar='c'; break;};
                        case 13 : {HexChar='d'; break;};
                        case 14 : {HexChar='e'; break;};
                        case 15 : {HexChar='f'; break;};
                    }
                }
                else {HexChar='*';};


                //if(i==sizeHex){full.append(UniNum);};


                //Add to the result string
                //HexNum.append(HexChar);
                UniNum.append(HexChar);
                full = BackSlash+UniNum;
            }//endfor
            DecNum++;
            cout<< full << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you edited it and not reposted

Comment: Ok..Next time I will make sure to update posts not to repost them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Universal Char rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402073/universal-char-rendering)

Comment: I have deleted the old post because a lot of ppl did not understand what i am asking .

Comment: You're generating strings of the form you see in the output. Your terminal does not do anything special for strings of that form. In the case of the embedded micro symbol μ, most likely your C++ execution character set is UTF-8 (common on *nix, even though it clashes with e.g. the standard library's character classification functions). In that case the character is represented in your executable as two bytes with values 0xC2 0xB5 (the UTF-8 encoding of μ).  With output to a terminal that expects UTF-8, these two bytes are presented as a μ character.

Comment: A good way to generate all (well, a lot of) Unicode characters is to use **wide text**, specifically the `wchar_t` type for the character encoding unit (the value that you generate) and a wide output stream such as `std::wcout`. To make that work in Unix-land, call `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" )` at the start of `main`.